# Why ASP.NET Core AddDataProtection Keys cannot be loaded from AppSettings.json

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-core

I want to know why there isn't an easy way to load your security keys from the AppSettings.json instead of loading them off the file system as XML?

Here is the example from the Microsoft documentation.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}")
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
});
```

I'm just wondering why there isn't something like the following.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToAppSetings("EncryptionKeys")
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
});
```

I don't understand why storing keys in an XML file would be any different than storing them in your AppSettigs.json. Now I know the format is different, however it's no more or less secure? correct?

I just want to be sure I'm not missing something.

Assumptions:

1. AppSettings.json is just as secure as some other XML file on disk
2. Azure AppSettings are securely stored and can only be access by permitted accounts
3. Azure AppSettings values would override any uploaded "developer" values
4. Developers will not store their production keys in source, surely right? :)
5. I know this would not work for expiring / recycling keys

Answer (score 1):

"It's complicated"

1. We create keys on demand.
2. We create multiple keys, just before a key expires, we create a new one.
3. We need keys to be synchronized between applications.
4. We need keys to be encrypted where possible.

AppSettings does not give us any of those things, applications can't update their own settings files so that rules out 1 and 2, web sites don't copy a changed app settings file between instances which rules out 3, and you can't encrypt things in app settings which rules out 4.

The format isn't the problem, you could write your own encryption wrapper to cope with #4, but the rest is still necessary, so now you have to change how settings works so they're read/write (and *safely* read write), and then persuade web hosts to support synchronization of your custom settings file between instances.

Comment: If you don't need 1, 2 then 3 isn't an issue. 4 is optional. So basically if you want limited term auto rotating keys then you need to store them somewhere that can happen? Correct?

Comment: We don't want you limiting auto-rotation. Never expiring keys is a bad security idea. This is what web.config had, and it was awful, lots of vulnerabilities around static keys. It is not a mistake we will make again. And no, 4 is not optional, not if you care about being secure.

Comment: OK, so how would one synchronize keys that are in Azure (file, database) with on premise server that need / want to be on premise? How do I sync these keys? FTP? Also who owns the key generation / rotation? Azure Server 1, 2, 3 or On Premise Server 4, 5, 6? Who generates the keys? What happens if Azure Server 2 generates a key at the same time as On Premise 6?

Comment: Also I'm down with option 4 of encrypt our keys (on disk, database), where do we store that encryption key? App Settings? Database? On Disk? How do we share this key?

Comment: Given your scenario, X509 Certificate in the certificate store. You can use a self signed on for this.

Comment: @blowdart is there any way to configure the location of key XML files via the appsettings.json without calling PersistKeysToFileSystem().